# nginx with unicorn frequently gives 502 bad gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have application that runs under nginx with unicorn. But sometimes it gives me the 502 bad gateway, and I'm not even trying to load a big page.

Also, my nginx just stops responding weirdly. I can see the request on my server but nothing happens.

My question is how can my nginx works properly with unicorn? Is there any tutorials or articles which could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was receiving this 502 for many reasons...

1) my web site wasn't optimized, there were too much ruby code on the views.

2)I was storing some images on Dropbox service, which was extremely slow (we changed to amazon, works great!).

3)I was running the application on a server of 700MB RAM, which using unicorn (that cosumes the shit out of the memory) was terrible.
So we changed to puma (much better).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment so I post here:
If you don't find any clear info in the logs and the 502 errors seams to be random, it may be a memory issue. You might want to check syslog for "out of memory" errors just in case your server is running out of memory while handling requests.

A few resources that might help you:

[Strange issue with unicorn and nginx caused 502 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133060/strange-issue-with-unicorn-and-nginx-caused-502-error?rq=1)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app

Edit: As you are running an UBUNTU server this may help you to see your memory usage:

```
$ free m # Will show you your current memory usage.
$ top # will show you you processes sorted by CPU usage. If you press Shift + M will sort them by memory usage.
$ sudo tail /var/log/syslog -n 50 # to see the last 50 lines in your syslog
$ sudo ls /var/log # To list most of your logging files in Ubuntu.
```

I hope this will help you identify your problem. Good luck!

Comment: I really don't think there's a out of memory problem. I only have one rails server running and there's like 5 users connected to the website.

Comment: Where can I check the syslog? btw i'm using a linux ubuntu server

Comment: As far as I know (I'm not a strong ubuntu user) most of the logging is stored in the /var/log/ folder. You can do: "sudo ls /var/log" to check it out. Then you can use Tail to see the last lines in whatever file you want. For example: "sudo tail /var/log/syslog -n 50". The "-n 50" part is not necessary but will show you the last 50 lines in the file. If not it would show you the last 10 lines only.

Comment: Ok, went to syslog and as expected there were no out of memory log

Comment: :( Good luck then! Sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: We are making some tests using rainbow and unicorn... I'll be back with some more updates